# Logical camera refence frame affecting GUI reference frame

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am using a sensor logical_camera as part of a radar plugin (github: https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_radar_plugin) which works perfectly fine; except when visualised ie. true

When set to true, in the GUI, all other objects spawn at the reference frame of the joint of the logical camera. If the unit box or sphere or cylinder is added using the GUI, the objects get spawned with the transformation of the joint frame (not at where the objects were placed using the mouse).

For example, if I set

```
<joint name="${name}_camera_joint" type="fixed">
<origin xyz="10 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
<parent link="${parent}"/>
<child link="${name}_link"/> </joint>
```

And then try to add a unit sphere using the GUI, upon clicking on a location, the sphere disappears and re-appears at a location 10m to the right (along the x-axis).

```
<gazebo reference="radar_mount">
    <sensor name="logical_camera" type="logical_camera">
      <logical_camera>
        <near>0.2</near>
        <far>2.0</far>
        <horizontal_fov>1.04719755</horizontal_fov>
        <aspect_ratio>1.778</aspect_ratio>
      </logical_camera>

      <visualize>false</visualize>
      <always_on>true</always_on>
      <update_rate>10</update_rate> 
    </sensor>
</gazebo>
```

And if the visualize is set to false, none of the above issues occur.

I am on ROS Indigo + Gazebo7. Any idea why this is happening?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/17876/logical-camera-refence-frame-affecting-gui-reference-frame/) by [ylchong](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4017/ylchong/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-11-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Sounds like this open issue:

https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/2240/logical-camera-pose-rotates-user-camera

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ylchong](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4017/ylchong/) on 2017-11-22**:
Yeah, looks like it is... Thanks! I ll mark as answered for now